# Fetching local data in firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have enabled the disk persistence in my android app

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
```

I want to schedule a service which first fetch the data in local cache then fetch data in firebase, compares and send notification to the user if there is a difference in data.

Is there any option in firebase which fetches local data eventhough the internet connectivity is available?

Comment: Firebase always synchronizes the data when there is Internet Connectivity. So there will never be a difference between them. If you want to compare offline data with new data on the server. I would recommend saving the offline data using Realm.io or SQLite. And then comparing with the Firebase Data.